# Python enum.Enum creates alias instead of new value

Tags: python, enums, alias, defaultdict

I just noticed a very weird behavior of Enum+defaultdict in pyhton. I define an enum like this, which collects some default dictionaries:

```
from enum import Enum
from collections import defaultdict

class A(Enum):
     a = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
     b = defaultdict(lambda: 2)
```

Then, when I look at what's inside A:

```
In [11]: A.a
Out[11]: <A.a: defaultdict(<function A.<lambda> at 0x7f773f03b510>, {})>

In [12]: A.b
Out[12]: <A.a: defaultdict(<function A.<lambda> at 0x7f773f03b510>, {})>
```

So `A.b` is just an alias to `A.a`. This looks a lot like a bug to me, even if there probably is some good reason behind. Any idea?

**Addendum**

Since it popped up in the comments, a note on why one would like to put a dict in an Enum. I find that it is very often useful to group constants into namespaces, so that one may access values as `A.a.constant1`, `A.b.constant1`, etc. At the moment, trying to do so with Enums raises an `AttributeError`. Of course, one could do something like:

```
class A:
    class a(Enum):
        constant1 = 1
    class b(Enum):
        constant1 = 2
```

However, this does not leverage on the capabilities of Enum (iteration, access via `__getitem__` etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you give two enum members equal values, `enum` will produce one enum member with two aliases rather than two distinct members.

Defaultdicts inherit equality comparison from `dict`. That means the default factory isn't part of `==` comparisons. Your enum members have equal values, so they get merged.

Using mutable objects as enum values is usually a bad idea. They tend to break `enum` design assumptions like "value equality doesn't change". Consider attaching these defaultdicts to your enum members in some other way.

Comment: Cristal clear. I find however the Enum implementation a bit disappointing. It gets very awkward if one wants to have an Enum-of-Enum, which to me looks like a rather common situation.

Comment: @ajc:  Do you have examples of enum of enums?

Comment: @EthanFurman I mean something which enables accessing groups of constants in a way like `A.a.foo`, `A.a.bar`, `A.b.foo`, `A.b.bar`,... I don't have an example because at the moment I am unable to create something like that.

Comment: @ajc:  You said it was a rather common situation, so I was hoping you could give a real world example even if you are unable to actually create it at the moment.